# How to start the Loop in second post of the blog

Tags: php, wordpress, post, blogs

I'm not an expert in PHP code but i need to fix this because it doesn't look good to have duplicate posts. Here's the link on my client website https://capitall.com.sg/blog/, As you can see we have a featured post and the list of post but the problem is the post is the same with featured post, We want to start into second post so there's no duplicated in post on the page. I hope you guys can help me

```
      <div id="news__wrapper" class="news__wrapper">
        <?php
          $load = 0;
          $total_post =wp_count_posts()->publish;
          if (null !== @$_GET['load']){
            $load = $_GET['load'];
          }
          $i = 6 + $load;
        ?>
        <?php 
          // the query
          $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=>$i,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'category_name' => @$_GET['category_id']
          ));
          $count = $wpb_all_query->found_posts;
        ?>
       
        <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
          <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="newsCard animate">
              <div class="newsCard__image-wrapper">
                <a class="newsCard__image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                  <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                  <img class="lazyload" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/images/img-placeholder.svg" data-src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt=""/>
                </a>
              </div>
              <a class="newsCard__tag" href="#">
                <?php 
                  $categories="";
                  foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){
                    $categories = $category->name.",";
                  }
                  echo substr($categories, 0, -1);
                ?>
              </a><a class="newsCard__title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
              <div class="newsCard__description"><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
          <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
          <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      <?php if( null == @$_GET['load'] && $count > 6 ) : ?>
        <div class="news__button animate">
          <a id="load_more" class="btn btn--big" ><?php the_field('load_more_button_label'); ?></a>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you tried adding `'offset' => 1`

Comment: Hi @Stender can you point it where to add this on my code?, Sorry I don't know much in PHP

Comment: not sure if it will break you pagination though - So be aware of that

Comment: It is added the same way as `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,`

Comment: Thank you so much @Stender It works, I really really appreciate it

Comment: Rather than messing with the pagination (which will work only if your featured post always is the _first_ post), I would use `post__not_in` – that allows you to exclude posts from the result based on their ID. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

Comment: @CBroe, but how would that be dynamic? then you would need a secondary query to get the latest post id, and exclude that?

Comment: @Stender why would one need to get any _latest_ post id? They said they had a _featured_ post here, so I would assume the ID of that is either known at that point already, or can at least easily be queried.

Comment: DevDietheR Is the featured post *always* the latest post? If so then offset is fine, but if its not then CBroe is right, and it is going to cause problems down the line. If that is the case, can you let us know how the featured post is identified in the system & displayed and the code that does this, so we can help you with a way of excluding it without preaking pagination.